# How to resolve cloud functions "Error: Argument "opStr" is not a valid QueryComparison. Operator must be one of "<", "<=", "==", ">", or ">="."

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
exports.calActivationPeriod = functions.https.onRequest((req,res)=>{

const postsArray = []

db.collection(`${PUBLIC_PROPERTIES}`).where('deleted',false).get()          
.then((querySnapshot)=>{

    console.log('posts collected: '+ querySnapshot.size);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{
        postsArray.push({poId:doc.id,
            activT:doc.data().activationTime,
            counter:doc.data().counter,
            userId:doc.data().userId,
            isActive:doc.data().isActive});
    });
return db.doc(`posts/count`).set(querySnapshot.size,{merge:true});

});
});
```

I used to run the above function and everything worked great ,I think only after i added "sharp" module of image processing the function started to fail and throw this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax should be `where('deleted','==',false)`

Comment: Lol, Can not believe how i missed that . thank you @Samuel Silva